# What is the most efficient way to delete hierarchies in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-delete, hierarchical-data

I am using a modified version of adjacency list to store hierarchical data. So a tree of this sort is created. [image]

### The same is represented in mysql schema in this way :

[image]
What is the best way to delete a node in between say C so that the children F, G are now children of A ?

Comment: Did you design the model? I don't think it is the best way to store hierarchical data, especially if you have to handle addition/deletion. Maybe take a look at [nested set model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) if you simply have 1:n relationships (see [this document](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) for examples).

Answer (score 0):

At application level you'll need to list down the childs of the node to be deleted and assign those childs' levels columns to parent node.
You can otherwise create a trigger on delete of node from the table which will do the above task.
If you would have structured your table correctly your all tasks would have been much easier.
table should have been just a parent child relation where immediate parent is saved.

```
 Id Name   ParentId
 1   A      NULL
 2   B      1
 3   D      2
```

levels can be determined by the no. of times recursion is done.
you can even do that now by adding the parent column and writing a script which would add the last levels available in the column.
So in this case, deletion would be simply
1. get list of childs   -  where parentid=nodeid.
2. updating their parent column with nodeids' parentid.

instead of updating and calculating all 3 level columns.